# Obtain percentage value with muliple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to show the percentage of cells marked "done" per floor, broken down by floor.
See example below.

Example Grid

[image: 1]

I would like the formula to do the following.

1. Count in column A the number of cells with the value of "5th floor"
2. Divide that number by the amount of rooms that are marked "Done" in column D for the 5th floor only.
3. Return the percentage of cells marked "Done" for the 5th floor.

I don't want to use absolute cell referances for cells marked "5th floor" as I will be adding to the data set constantly and would like the formula to automatically recalculate the number of done rooms on the 5th floor if another row is added.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to include your attempt to point out which functions you have tried so far that didn't work to get desired results. Pointer: Have you tried to devide `COUNTIFS()` by `COUNTIF()` yet?

Comment: My apoligies, I tried the following formula and I am not sure how to add a conditional into the second "COUNTIF" to only count the "dones" in column D that corespond to the "5th floor" cells in column A, as opposed to all the "dones" in column D.

Comment: =COUNTIF(A:A,"5th floor")/COUNTIF(D:D, "Done")

Comment: The answer is in my previous comment. Use `COUNTIFS()` first. Then decide by `COUNTIF()`.

Comment: Your formula does not divide by the amount of "5th floor rooms" that are done as you did not mention that criteria in the formula. Use COUNTIFS with both criteria instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to using functions so this is a bit over my head. I am not sure how to use COUNTIFS with both criteria. Could you help me understand this better by showing the exact formula I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  Wow, did I ever dork THAT up, thanks to JvdV for straightening me out.  Indeed was the one with the order flipped.  Here they are in the correct order.  As before, eitherof these should produce the result you intended:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Fifth Floor",D:D,"Done") / COUNTIFS(A:A,"Fifth Floor")

=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Fifth Floor",D:D,"Done") / COUNTIF(A:A,"Fifth Floor")
```

COUNTIFS(range1,criteria1,range2,criteria2) means "count the number of rows where range1=criteria1 AND range2=criteria2 are BOTH true.

Further to JdvD's comment, you can set the cell format to be "Percent" from the menu, or you can impose it from the formula if you prefer that by using the TEXT() function and using something like "0%" or "0.0" as the format descriptor.  Thus:

```
=TEXT(COUNTIFS(A:A,"Fifth Floor",D:D,"Done") / COUNTIFS(A:A,"Fifth Floor"),"0%")
```

Comment: Thank you Max. This was very helpful however it did not produce the result intended, I am pretty sure this is because I am not explaining what I want to do very well, so please forgive me.

I managed to get the desired result I wanted by breaking down the formula into 3 different cells.

If you could tell me how to combine all three formulas that would solve my problem.

FORMULA 1: =COUNTIF(A:A,"5th floor")

RESULT = 3

FORMULA 2: =COUNTIFS(D:D, "Done",A:A,"5th floor")

RESULT =1

3. Then divide the results of  formulas #1 and #2 multiplied by 100 to obtain the percentage.

Comment: No, the comments above are not wrong, they are right. Use: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"5th floor",D:D,"Done")/COUNTIF(A:A,"5th floor")` and format the result through number formatting to percentage data type.